# White space around matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm a real python newbie and can't seem to get this animation to look how I want. I've made a similar plot without animation, and that appears nicely in the Jupyter notebook, with little whitespace. However, when I add animation to the plot, it looks really ugly! Here is my code:

```
%%capture
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.animation as animation
plt.rcParams["animation.html"] = "jshtml"

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 9))

# Set map area and set to display coastlines, country borders etc.
ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 0.99, 0.99], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-130, -10, 0, 40], ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.background_patch.set_visible(False)
ax.outline_patch.set_visible(True)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='whitesmoke')
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

# selects which data to plot, from larger dataframe
gd = (df_plot.Name == "IRMA")
Long_vals = df_plot.loc[gd,'Long'].values
Lat_vals = df_plot.loc[gd,'Lat'].values
data = np.array([Long_vals,Lat_vals])

# set up empty plot
l, = ax.plot([], [], c='red')

# define how to add points to plot in animation
def update_track(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[..., :num])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_track, fargs=(data, l),
                               frames=60, interval=50, 
                               blit=True, repeat=False)
```

At the moment, the bottom of my plot looks like this... with a similar amount of whitespace at the top and sides. Can I make it fit in more flush to the rest of the notebook? Thanks.

[image]